# How to re-factor 2 functions which are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I'm working on an accessible carousel with my weak javascript knowledge, and I'm facing a syntax problem.

Here is the part that gives me a problem :

```
events: function () {
    var self = this;
this.target.on('click', '.nav-right, .right', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.moveCarousel(self.target.find('.carousel-wrapper li'), 'left', 'right', function (cur, $el) {
        if (cur === $el.length - 1) {
            return '0';
        }

        return cur + 1;
    });
});

this.target.on('focus', '.nav-right, .right', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.moveCarousel(self.target.find('.carousel-wrapper li'), 'left', 'right', function (cur, $el) {
        if (cur === $el.length - 1) {
            return '0';
        }

        return cur + 1;
    });
});
```

here is the full code if that's important (121 lines) : http://jsfiddle.net/12b63z7e/

Now, what is the purpose of that function ? I simply want that the slide event fires both on click and on focus. The problem is, with how I wrote it, basically copy pasting the click function for the focus function, that JS doesnt fire the first function anymore (I cant slide on click now). So I think I need to rewrite those 2 functions in a single function that would slide the item both on focus and on click.

Please ask me any questions if something is not clear

Comment: It's as easy as adding both events to the handler -> `this.target.on('click focus' ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a space separated list of event names to on() to register the same handler to multiple events on same elements

```
events: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.target.on('click focus', '.nav-right, .right', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.moveCarousel(self.target.find('.carousel-wrapper li'), 'left', 'right', function (cur, $el) {
            if (cur === $el.length - 1) {
                return '0';
            }

            return cur + 1;
        });
    });
```

Comment: damn, thanks I feel stupid for asking now. I will accept your answer when the timer allows it